# Is there an access modifier that I can use hiding a abstract method from being called in a derived type?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Say I have a class1 that derives from abstract class2.  Class2 has an abstract method that each derived class must override.  In my design the method will only be called if class1 is casted to class2.  Is there a way to hide this method when it is casted as class1?  Not really a problem for me if not just wondering.  If it is possible is this a good/bad idea and why?  Thanks!!!

Comment: what would be the point of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? Secondly, it would be really useful to know why you need to do this.

Comment: The point is the derived classes need this method because it will be different for each of them but is only going to be called when the derived types are casted to the base type.  Basically just to have one less available method to call in the derived types since it woun't be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use explicit interface implementation to achieve a similar effect. To call an explicitly implemented interface method you need to cast to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt it. It's not how inheritance is supposed to work in Object Oriented Design.

If Class1 doesn't have Class2 abstract method then it shouldn't inherit from class2.

Imagine a user having a collection of class2 and calling .abstractMethod() on each and every one in it. Later someone adds a instance of Class1 to it.

Neither of these programmers did anything wrong but the code still doesn't work.

Consider adding one more level of abstract here so that top level abstract has all feature class1 and class2 have and they both inherit from it. Class2 then adds the abstractMethod.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea because it goes against the SOLID principle, especially the L part of the principle. If someone else was trying to use your derived class knowing that inherits from the base class which already has the method, he'd be very much confused about the incomplete implementation, especially since it's an abstract method. Interface is the way to go, as previously stated, you can define an explicit implementation and effectivelly hide the method.

Comment: I think it makes a lot of sense to have a method that can be overridden but not called in the derived class. It's problem is that this prevents to usual forwarding from the derived to base method. Afaik C++ supports something similar, namely private virtual methods.